# Can I get access to this in Vue3 component emit?

Tags: vue.js

I got components that emit stuff...

```
<li v-for="multigate in store.availableMultigates">
  <Multigate :multigate="multigate" @antennas="showAntennas" />
</li>
```

...like this (inside the component):

```
emit('antennas', connectedAntennas.value )
```

This is how the function looks:

```
const showAntennas = (connectedAntennas) => {
  console.log(connectedAntennas)
}
```

Is it possible that in the function I get access to the 'multigate' instance (from the v-for loop)? Or to maybe to 'this'? If yes, how?

Comment: You look for $event magic local var. It can be `@antennas="showAntennas"` instead and receive event value without specifying it

Comment: What happens if you change this line: `<Multigate :multigate="multigate" @antennas="showAntennas()" />` to `<Multigate :multigate="multigate" @antennas="showAntennas" />`

Comment: the brackets are a mistake. I was playing around and forgot to delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The live gist is here.](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Bind the event listener to a function, not to an JS expression `showAntennas()`. So you will get your event params in the function arguments:

```
<script setup>
    
  import Multigate from './Multigate.vue';
  
  import { ref } from 'vue';

  const $log = ref();
  
  function showAntennas(multigate){
    $log.value.textContent = JSON.stringify(multigate);
  }

</script>

<template>
  <Multigate :multigate="{multigate:true}" @antennas="showAntennas" />
  <div ref="$log"></div>
</template>
```

Multigate.vue

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['multigate']);
</script>
<template>
    <button @click="$emit('antennas', multigate)">Emit antennas</button>
</template>
```